# Contra - 30 More Lives

Tags: javascript, jquery, game

Just for the fun of it, I wanted to have a hidden `keypress` function on my website that performs an event when the user types in the [Contra code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) for thirty lives. I'm curious how the implementation for this simple piece of code holds up and where it could be improved.

*Note: `keypress` doesn't seem to detect the arrow keys so I used the arrows from the numpad*

```
var codeCount = 0;


//[up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a, start]
var contraCode = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65, 13];

$(window).keydown(function(input) {
  var key = input.which;
  if (contraCode[codeCount] === key) {
     codeCount++;

     //if 11 keys have sequentially matched the cheat code 
     if (codeCount === 11) {
        alert('You got 30 lives!');
     }
  }
  else {
     codeCount = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: What's does contraCode represent? Please display the full snippet

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo It seems to be a [joke or Easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code).

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo 'contraCode' is an array of elements where each element is the integer value of the key being pressed by the keyboard. For example, when a user presses the UP arrow key, 'key = 38'. When the user presses the 'a' key, 'key = 65'.

Comment: @200_success , that was my thought when I read the post ^.^ - Cheers Mate

Comment: keypress is only for printable characters (on screen characters)- as you already guessed keydown is the best option

Answer (score 7):

One thing you could improve is to remove the jQuery dependency and just use `addEventListener` directly. This should be fine as all modern browsers support this already. Although, the tradeoff would be to normalize your keycodes yourself.

Also, I would suggest separating the code that updates `codeCount` from the code that checks if you achieved all keys in sequence. This way, there's clear separation in logic. The one problem I often come across with code not clearly separating logic is that in the long run, code becomes hard to untangle. Kill this habit while still early.

Taking it a bit further, you can assign the key values to an object. This way, you can represent the key in code using a enum-like structure and avoid hardcoding keycodes all over your code. This also allows you to change the keycode value without having to dive in to the code to find and change keycodes everywhere.

```
var codeCount = 0;

var Keys = {
  UP: 38,
  DOWN: 40,
  LEFT: 37,
  RIGHT: 39,
  B:66,
  A: 65,
  START: 13,
];

//[up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a, start]
var contraCode = [
  Keys.UP,
  Keys.UP,
  Keys.DOWN,
  Keys.DOWN,
  Keys.LEFT,
  Keys.RIGHT,
  Keys.LEFT,
  Keys.RIGHT,
  Keys.B,
  Keys.A,
  Keys.START,
];

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){

  var key = event.keyCode? event.keyCode : event.charCode;

  codeCount = contraCode[codeCount] === key ? codeCount + 1 : 0;

  if(codeCount === 11) alert('You got 30 lives!');

});
```

Answer (score 5):

### Scopes and global variables

Your code looks very good; it's a fairly simple task, so there isn't too much to review. However, I'm going to suggest a different design that will keep things modular as right now you just have floating global variables which aren't good at all.

To keep your variables in the same scope, you should encapsulate everything inside a function.

```
function checkContraCode() {
    ...
}
```

However, there's a problem with this: your variable `codeCount` needs to keep its state, so if we just drop it in the function, then it will lose its state every call.

So, that means we need to have this function return another function like this:

```
function checkContraCode() {
    //[up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a, start]
    var contraCode = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65, 13];
    var codeCount = 0;

    return function(input) {
      var key = input.which;
      if (contraCode[codeCount] === key) {
         codeCount++;

         //if 11 keys have sequentially matched the cheat code 
         if (codeCount === 11) {
            alert('You got 30 lives!');
         }
      }
      else {
         codeCount = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Now this satisfies the idea of keeping everything in it's own scope, and it can be used quite easily:

```
$(window).keydown = checkContraCode();
```

---

### `keyup` vs `keydown`

You should probably use the `keyup` event instead of the `keydown` event as with the latter event, if the user accidentally holds down the key, then multiple events will be registered in quick succession; the `keyup` event will only be fired once (when the user lets go of the key).

---

### Usefulness

> ```
> alert('You got 30 lives!');
> ```

That is not useful; all it does is tell the user that they have gained 30 lives; nothing actually happens in the program logic.

I assume you have more code to go along with this. That being said, you should probably pass in a function from another part of your code that will make this actually do something.

```
function checkContraCode(onSuccess) {
    //[up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a, start]
    var contraCode = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65, 13];
    var codeCount = 0;

    return function(input) {
      var key = input.which;
      if (contraCode[codeCount] === key) {
         codeCount++;

         //if 11 keys have sequentially matched the cheat code 
         if (codeCount === 11) {
            onSuccess();
         }
      }
      else {
         codeCount = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$(window).keyup = checkContraCode(otherFunction);
```